# Macro photography Close Up

Tags: nikon

I am having trouble getting good depth of field on close photos. My light is good. Lense is AF-S Micro Nikkor 40 MM 1:2.8 G

Comment: "I am having trouble getting good depth of field on close photos." Welcome to the club. So does everyone else!

Comment: Macro photography has a tiny depth of field, but if you are unsure maybe you can post an example or two as a link and tell us your shutter speed and aperture and tell us why you think it is an issue.

Comment: The higher magnification the shallow DoF. You can try to help yourself to use higher apperture values and longer times/higher ISO.

Comment: Macro photography close up,  that's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Use the smallest aperture your lens is capable of.
The smaller the aperture the longer depth of field.
F16 to f64 or f128.
Use the slowest ISO that provide enough light or add light
If you can.
Shutter speed is at least 60th of a second.

Another trick is zoom out as far as you can until your depth of field covers all subjects  then  use photoshop to zoom in.